# DomElement object - Specify which sibling I require?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Is there a neater / better way of traversing my DomElement Object?

In particular, when I am looking to get values 4, 5 and 6, I am thinking that there must be a better way of getting nodes than `->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling` etc...? Is there a method available which would enable me to specify the sibling which I require?

```
public function fire()
{
    $url = "http://test.com";
    $html = $this->downloadPage($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $myXpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="test_table"]');

    if (!is_null($myXpath)) 
    {
        $domElement = $myXpath->item(0);
            $parent = $domElement->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->firstChild->nextSibling;
            $value1 = $parent->nodeValue;
            $value2 = $parent->nextSibling->nodeValue;
            $value3 = $parent->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue;

            $this->info("Value 1: " . $value1);
            $this->info("Value 2: " . $value2);
            $this->info("Value 3: " . $value3);
    }
    else {
        $this->info("Error");
    }
}
```

The table has the following structure

```
<table id="test_table">
    <tr>
        <td width="40"></td> // Dont Want
        <td width="55"></td> // Dont Want
        <td width="55"></td> // Dont Want
        <td width="55"></td> // Dont Want
    </tr>
<!--A comment--> // Dont Want
    <tr>
        <td>AM</td>
        <td class="pricing">aaa</td>  // Value1
        <td class="pricing">bbb</td>  // Value2
        <td class="pricing">ccc</td>  // Value3
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PM</td>
        <td class="pricing">ddd</td>  // Value4
        <td class="pricing">eee</td>  // Value5
        <td class="pricing">fff</td>  // Value6
    </tr>
<!--Updated 10:31 18/10/2013--> // I want this date comment
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td> // Dont Want
        <td colspan="3" align="right"></td> // Dont Want
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what exactly you are needing, but it sounds like you want to get the values from the cells with the class of `pricing` and also get the `Updated` comment.

```
// Get the table, to use as a context node for the other queries
$table = $xpath->query('//table[@id="test_table"]')->item(0);

// Get cells with class="pricing"
$pricings = $xpath->query('descendant::td[@class="pricing"]', $table);
foreach ($pricings as $pricing) {
    // E.g. $text = $pricing->nodeValue;
    var_dump($doc->saveXML($pricing));
}

// Get the "Updated ..." comment
$updated_query = 'string(descendant::comment()[starts-with(., "Updated ")])';
$updated = $xpath->evaluate($updated_query, $table);
var_dump($updated);
```

<kbd>[See this example's output](https://eval.in/55343)</kbd>

Comment: Aaah, thanks for this. I tried to do something similar, but it was breaking. Without the `->item(0)`, in the first xpath query, I was not able to run the second xpath query. So I thought that this was not possible. Thanks for your help. I did rephrase question to make clearer. Is there a way of specifying a node value of a specific child instead of iterating through?

Comment: e.g. from your example: is it possible to do something like the following instead of foreach, `$pricings->item(3)->nodeValue`?

Comment: Yes, like that. The `$pricings` variable is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist) (representing a collection of DOM nodes). The [`item()`](http://php.net/domnodelist.item) method retrieves a single node, which in your case will be a [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/domelement) object and as such you can access its [`nodeValue`](http://php.net/domnode#domnode.props.nodevalue) property. And remember, the number provided to `item()` is zero-based.